# Kendo grid add new entry

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have two pages in which there is one grid in each page. When I press a custom button of one grid I need to open the add new entry of the other grid in the other page.

I will explain it with my situation I have two pages customers and enquiries in each page having one grid. The customer grid is having a custom command add enquiry. When I press this button I should open the add new Enquiry of the enquiries grid in the enquiries page.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I am in a bit hurry it will be really helpful if anyone can answer.

Comment: If those pages are really two seperate pages it may be better to add a custom button and create a custom editing to save it for the other page's grid.

Comment: can't i open the add new enquiry window by navigating from customers to enquiries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite simple just call grid.addRow() method after routing to that page as shown below

```
var grid = $("#gridId").data("kendoGrid");
grid.addRow();
```

This will open the add new entry.